# How to play a wave file using Windows Multimedia API (winmm.dll) in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, audio, playback, winmm

I'm working on a wave file playback system, but I'm having trouble getting proper playback output using `winmm.dll`

The problems I'm experiencing are:

1. The playback stops abruptly.
2. The playback speeds up or breaks up or both.
3. There is no playback at all.
4. The 'Stop' method causes the system to hang on a `Thread.Join` call.

I do realize that there are alternatives to playing sound files in C#, WPF, but I'm trying to achieve it through `winmm.dll` with `.wav` files specifically because it will allow me *(***I hope***) to build specific features such as: **Wave File Visualization** and **Sound Effect Filters**.

I have looked at this Code Project link:

[Programming Audio Effects in C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3382/Programming-Audio-Effects-in-C)

It's very insightful, but I'm unable to achieve similar results in WPF. I'm not sure if the problems have to do with *Garbage Collection* that works differently from Windows Forms to WPF.

Here's my project on GitHub:

[Wave Player - Base - WPF and Windows Forms](https://github.com/Shiasu-sama/Wave-Player---Base)

The solution has 2 projects: One is Windows Forms and the other is WPF.
The Windows Forms project works fine, the WPF doesn't. Both the projects, however, uses the same `winmm.dll` code logic.

I've also found this Microsoft link on 'Waveform Audio' :

[Microsoft - About Waveform Audio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/multimedia/about-waveform-audio)

Any help or advice will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think the GC is any different when Winforms code is running, or WPF. The GC is just part of .NET. There could be something else however that has some effect.

Comment: I think you should create the most minimal possible examples of what happens in WinForms & WPF and post that code directly in your question. Its a good exercise anyway to do that to try and narrow down the problem.

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs I've broken it down to the smallest I can, but the code is still around 600 lines of code, per project. So Windows Forms is ~600 lines of code and then the WPF is a very similar ~600 lines of code. Is it ok to post that much code into the question itself?

Comment: That might be a lot for people to read through... I would think though that you could make a very contrived minimal example that has only the most essential parts in less than that?